# React Native: How to format payment in mm/yy and spaced 16-digit card number in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, react-native, reactjs

In React Native, I have two `<TextInput/>`, one which receives MM/YY and the other 16-digit card number.

In the first input for MM/YY, I have:

```
  <TextInput
    onChangeText={this._handlingCardExpiry.bind(this)}
    placeholder='MM/YY'
    value={cardExpiry}
  />
```

And for the 16-digit card number:

```
  <TextInput
    onChangeText={this._handlingCardNumber.bind(this)}
    placeholder='0000 0000 0000 0000'
    value={cardNumber}
  />
```

For the expiry, I attempted to split them up and store in the value property as `${cardMonth}/${cardYear}`, but the text would not even rather, and adding space after every 4 digits to the card number input cause texts to not appear in the input.

**What would be the right approach to handling the following with the < TextInput />'s onChangeText and value properties:**

1. When a user starts typing in `<TextInput/>`, show a `/` in the middle and inputting first two digits would appear before the `/` and next two after.
2. When a user starts typing in 16-digit card number, automatically place space after every 4 digits entered in.

Thank you in advance and will vote up/accept the answer.

Comment: have you tried using state

Answer (score 13):

I'll add the handling card number, since it was part of the original question:

```
_handlingCardNumber(number) {
  this.setState({
    cardNumber: number.replace(/\s?/g, '').replace(/(\d{4})/g, '$1 ').trim()
  });
}
```

where:

```
  <TextInput
    onChangeText={(text) => this._handlingCardNumber(text)}
    placeholder='0000 0000 0000 0000'
    value={this.state.cardNumber}
  />
```

Comment: I actually gave it a try and the space actually increments as you put more card numbers, so with 16 digits, I eventually ended up with `1111            2222        4444    5555`. Also, how can I turn it back to 16 digits without space?

Comment: I updated the solution to remove user added / extra spaces from the input.

Comment: It works nicely but could you explain what it is doing? Trying to learn as well. Also, how can I turn it back to just 16 digits without space?

Comment: Just checking in to see if you've seen my previous comment. Please let me know.

Answer (score 8):

You should be using a state variable to update your `TextInput` value, so that each time the text changes, you can handle the change and update the state, thereby updating the value as you want within the component. For example, try the following:

```
<TextInput
    onChangeText={this._handlingCardExpiry.bind(this)}
    placeholder='MM/YY'
    keyboardType={'numeric'}
    value={this.state.cardExpiry}
   />
```

Above, I have changed the value of `TextInput` to be `this.state.cardExpiry`. You can do something similar for the other component. Also note that I've added `keyboardType={'numeric'}` which essentially provides the user with a keyboard that only allows them to input numbers. Below, I'll show you how to handle a text change and update the state.

```
_handlingCardExpiry(text) {
    if (text.indexOf('.') >= 0 || text.length > 5) {
        // Since the keyboard will have a decimal and we don't want
        // to let the user use decimals, just exit if they add a decimal
        // Also, we only want 'MM/YY' so if they try to add more than
        // 5 characters, we want to exit as well
        return;
    }

    if (text.length === 2 && this.state.cardExpiry.length === 1) {
        // This is where the user has typed 2 numbers so far
        // We can manually add a slash onto the end
        // We check to make sure the current value was only 1 character
        // long so that if they are backspacing, we don't add on the slash again
        text += '/'
    }

    // Update the state, which in turns updates the value in the text field
    this.setState({
        cardExpiry: text
    });
}
```

You can try this code and tweak it to fit your needs, but this is the general concept. You can apply similar formatting to your 16-digit field, where every 4 digits you add a space before updating the state.

Comment: I gave it a try, but once I enter in the second digit, I get an error at `if (text.length === 2 && this.state.cardExpiry.length === 1)` saying `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`.

Comment: @KuNole Sorry, in your constructor you should have the line `this.state = { cardExpiry: '' }` As of right now, it's trying to check the length of an undefined value, because you haven't given it an initial state.

Comment: I had the initial state but still getting `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`. But shouldn't it not be getting the error despite not having the initial state? Because, the text is entered in first and then that is checked for the length?

Comment: Just checking in to see if you've seen my previous comment. Please let me know.